# ruby Unit Test problem

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

Have been trying to get the following code to work, but can't; it says I'm calling a private method.

What am I doing wrong?

```
    def subtotal(price, qty = 1)
      return nil if price.to_f<= 0 || qty.to_f <= 0
      price.to_f * qty.to_f
    end

    puts subtotal(12.93)
    puts subtotal(12.93, 3)
    puts subtotal(456.82, 6)

     def subtotal(qty = 1)
       return nil if price.to_f<= 0 || qty.to_f <= 0
       self.to_f * qty.to_f
     end

     book = 39.99
     car = 16789

     puts book.subtotal(3)
     puts car.subtotal
     puts car.subtotal(7)
```

Comment: I'll second what Matchu has said -- we'd need at least the actual error message, and ideally all the code, to help properly.  But it looks as if subtotal() as been defined as private somewhere.  Try changing the name of this method to something else?

Answer (score 0):

Though I'd like more information, like the full class definition and the error trace, since the public method `to_f` is the only other method call here, I'm guessing that `subtotal` is defined as a private method.

In a Ruby class definition, keywords like `public`, `protected`, and `private` apply to *all* methods that come after the keyword. Check that the `subtotal` definition is not below `private` or `protected` in the class definition.

If not, then the issue likely lies elsewhere. Check that error trace, and look at where the error *actually* comes from.

Comment: OK, thank you. How do I check if the method is public, protected or private? Should I use the keyword public before the method?

Answer (score 0):

Your subtotal works in two different environments.

One time, its a 'stand alone method', the other time it's a Numeric-method. So, lets define them as Numeric-method:

```
def subtotal(price, qty = 1)
  return nil if price <= 0 || qty <= 0
  price * qty
end

class Numeric
   def subtotal(qty = 1) #only one paramter. The other is 'self'
     return nil if self <= 0 || qty <= 0
     self * qty
   end
 end

puts subtotal(12.93)
puts subtotal(12.93, 3)
puts subtotal(456.82, 6)


 book = 39.99
 car = 16789

 puts book.subtotal(3)
 puts car.subtotal
 puts car.subtotal(7)
```

Remark on my code: I don't see a real reason for converting to Floats. If you start with Fixnums (see your car-example), then my solution works also. Perhaps, you need the conversion for your specific case.

From your example code I would prefer to define a Articcle class:

```
def subtotal(price, qty = 1)
  return nil if price <= 0 || qty <= 0
  price * qty
end

class Article
    def initialize(price = 0)
        @price = price
      end
   def subtotal(qty = 1)
     return nil if @price <= 0 || qty <= 0
     @price * qty
   end
 end

puts subtotal(12.93)
puts subtotal(12.93, 3)
puts subtotal(456.82, 6)


 book = Article.new(39.99)
 car = Article.new(16789)

 puts book.subtotal(3)
 puts car.subtotal
 puts car.subtotal(7)
```